# Заменить пробелы в колонке таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Делаю запрос так:

```
SELECT REPLACE(`url`, ' ', '_') FROM `table`;
```

получаю ответ

```
Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

 Showing rows 0 - 499 (13317 total, Query took 0.0002 seconds.)
```

Если устанавливать primary key , то ответ

```
#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'url' used in key specification without a key length
```

Как сделать замену в таблице правильно?

Comment: Давайте DDL таблицы

Comment: И первая ошибка - это не ошибка MySQL. Расскажите где Вы ее получаете и когда? При выполнении SELECT или что-то пытаетесь еще делать?

Comment: Только SELECT. Нужно полностью колонки прописывать. Тогда замечания нет, но и замены тоже нет. Не Пойму почему пробел остается?

Comment: Какая замена? SELECT не заменяет данные. Он их только выбирает. Что Вы делаете?

Comment: Задача: Заменить пробелы в колонке url таблицы table  MySQL Как сделать правильный запрос? `SELECT REPLACE(`url`, ' ', '_') FROM `table`;`

Answer (score 0):

Для mysql 5.5 сработало следующее:

```
update `table` set `url` = replace(`url`, ' ', '_')
```

Comment: Это сработает в любой версии MySQL. Ошибка `Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.` означает, что полученные из MySQL данные показываются в клиенте для редактирования. А клиент не сможет отредактировать эти данные, так как не знает, откуда они пришли - в результирующей таблице (любой SELECT запрос к БД возвращает таблицу) нет первичного ключа, чтобы отправить назад запрос на `UPDATE ... WHERE {первичный ключ} = ...`